# Publishing a web site: from a directory tree to server

Tags: bash, shell, web

Does anyone know of a script to publish a web site directory hierarchy to a web server from a local git repo?  I'm trying to avoid re-inventing the wheel.

I was thinking the solution could either be scripted visiting file by file or a directory tree using rsync.  If scripted file by file, a configuration file would contain tuples; each file to be published and its permissions.  This configuration file may also contain path names for folders to be created as well.

Appreciate your guidance.

Comment: `rsync` is fine, just exclude the `.git` directory when syncing. If permissions are different on the server, then just create a short script to run after the sync that would set the permission server-side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use rsync and ssh with the chmod command to edit permission after syncing the directories.